# I'm trying to display my current location on a map but it wont display the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This app is supposed to display the users current location on a map.I use the `FusedLocationProviderClient` class to get this work done, getting the users current known location and displaying it to the user through a Toast and on the map.

The app is working but my issue is that no map gets displayed once the app is launched, only the toast

**MainActivity Code:**

````
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private  static int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this) ;
        fetchLastLocation();
    }


    private void fetchLastLocation() {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if(location!=null)
                    currentLocation = location;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentLocation.getLatitude()+ "" + currentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
               assert supportMapFragment!=null;
               supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {


                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }


        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }  ```
````

Comment: You have to enable google map sdk for android in google api console to show map in app. Please check that.

Comment: I have tried this but it wont work

Comment: did you check your logcat there will be error from google ?